# How to switch to iFrame, not working in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on an object within the iframe, but I can't switch frames for some reason.

This is the code that I am using to switch frames:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="practice_schedule"]'))
```

This is the HTML path:
[image: HTML]

Any solutions?

Comment: Why do you think it didn't switch? what happens when you try this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find_elements_by_xpath` return list, remove `s` from it, what you want is `.find_element_by_xpath` to select first element.